# Configure my Droid 4 to AutoConnect via Bluetooth to my PC?

Tags: bluetooth, motorola-droid

I have paired my Droid 4 with my Windows 7 Professional x64 PC. However, whenever I turn Bluetooth on, on my phone, it fails to auto-connect to the PC. It says the following when I look at the Bluetooth Settings:

> Paired but not Connected

I have to click on the pairing just to get it to connect. Is there any way to get my phone to auto-connect once it's in range of my PC, or to put the pairing on the desktop so it's a widget that is easy to click to get it to connect?

I've googled around but most of the material I've found is for auto-connecting to car stereos.

Comment: why do you need it to connect? you can do everything you would be able to anyway cant you? I mean if you want to send a file etc you can without connecting